# Spark SQL find min value in column and get whole row

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table like below and I want to get row where distance in min in spark sql

I tried this

```
result.select($"sourceBorder", $"targetBorder", $"min(distance))").show()
```

which gives error, and result.agg(min("distance")) only gives the distance column not others.

```
+------------+------------+--------+
|sourceBorder|targetBorder|distance|
+------------+------------+--------+
|           3|          12|      20|
|           4|          12|      28|
|           2|          12|      16|
|           3|           6|      15|
|           4|           6|      19|
|           2|           6|       7|
|           3|           7|      15|
|           4|           7|      23|
|           2|           7|      11|
+------------+------------+--------+
```

so at the end want this row

```
|           2|           6|       7|
```

Comment: I sorted and get the first row but I don't know is it the best way

`result.sort($"distance".asc).head()`

Answer (score 4):

Add a column of minimum distance, and filter the rows where distance = minimum distance:

```scala
result.withColumn(
    "mindistance",
    min($"distance").over(Window.orderBy("distance"))
).filter($"distance" === $"mindistance")
```